# Pyomo: passing information from one optimisation to another

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I've been slowly building up an energy dispatch model using Pyomo, which now has most of the dispatch constraints that I want included.

Now comes for what I think may be the tricky bit. To avoid the problem of perfect foresight, I want to optimise one day at a time. When I optimise each subsequent day, the model will be passed new information: information on the load point and whether each unit is committed, from the previous day's result. At the moment my model just runs each day independently, and churns out a json file with the outputs from each day.

I think I now want to modify the workflow so that:

- I optimise for day 'd'
- Grab selected outputs from the optimisation of 'd'
- These outputs become initial condition for 'd+1'
- Optimise 'd+1'

Subsequently, I will add look-aheads into the code, but I think that will be straight-forward once I have cracked the above.

I think I could work this out by writing some code that processes the outputs from 'd' outside of Pyomo, creates a new set of inputs to 'd+1' and then goes back to Pyomo for optimise 'd+1', but that feels like a cumbersome solution that might be quite slow. Is anyone able to point me towards an example or guidance on how I might tackle this in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little something to help post process all parameters and variables of a Pyomo model after solve.
This may help you easily get all your outputs and put them as inputs in your next iteration.
Good luck.
https://github.com/judejeh/PyomoSolverWrapper

Comment: Many thanks for this! I'll be coming back to this in a few days so will let you know how I get on.